# Im using JS inside PHP and for some reason the JS won't go to the else if even when the If isn't true

Tags: javascript, php

As the Title suggests, the code below is some JS inside of a PHP file and for some reason the JS won't go to the else if even when the if isn't true. At it's current state, which ever if statement is put first will run correctly but then the second one will never fire. All this system is designed to do is run x queries when staff === true and run y queries when user == true

session.php

```
    <?php
// mysqli_connect() function opens a new connection to the MySQL server.
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sports world");
session_start();// Starting Session
// Storing Session
$user_check = $_SESSION['login_user2'];
$p = $_SESSION['login_user3'];
?>

<script>
if sessionStorage.getItem('status2') === 'staff') {
    <?php
    // SQL Query To Fetch Information Of User
    $query = "SELECT Username from staff where Username = '$user_check'";
    $ses_sql = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);

    $login_session = $row['Username'];


    // SQL Query To Fetch Information Of User
    $query2 = "SELECT StaffCode from staff where Username = '$user_check' AND Password = '$p'";
    $ses_sql2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ses_sql2);

    $cust = $row2['StaffCode'];
    $_SESSION['CustCode'] = $cust;


    // SQL Query To Fetch Information Of User
    $query3 = "SELECT StaffGivenName As 'Given Name', StaffSurname As 'Surname' from staff where StaffCode = '$cust'";
    $ses_sql3 = mysqli_query($conn, $query3);
    $row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ses_sql3);

    $name1 = $row3['Given Name'];
    $name2 = $row3['Surname'];
    $_SESSION['Given Name'] = $name1;
    $_SESSION['Surname'] = $name2;


    // SQL Query To Fetch Information Of User
    $queryAccountDeatils = "SELECT StaffDob As 'Date of Birth', StaffGender As 'Gender', StaffAddress1 As 'Address', StaffAddress2 As 'Region', StaffPostCode As 'Post Code', StaffPhone As 'Phone Number', StaffEmail As 'Email', StaffTFN As 'Message Preferences', StaffEmerConName As 'Member Type', StaffEmerConPhone As 'Sports' from staff where StaffCode = '$cust'";
    $ses_sql4 = mysqli_query($conn, $queryAccountDeatils);
    $row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ses_sql4);

    $Dob = $row4['Date of Birth'];
    $Address = $row4['Address'];
    $Gender = $row4['Gender'];
    $Region = $row4['Region'];
    $PostCode = $row4['Post Code'];
    $PhoneNumber = $row4['Phone Number'];
    $Email = $row4['Email'];
    $MessagePref = $row4['Message Preferences'];
    $MemberType = $row4['Member Type'];
    $Sports = $row4['Sports'];
    $_SESSION['Date of Birth'] = $Dob;
    $_SESSION['Address'] = $Address;
    $_SESSION['Gender'] = $Gender;
    $_SESSION['Region'] = $Region;
    $_SESSION['Post Code'] = $PostCode;
    $_SESSION['Phone Number'] = $PhoneNumber;
    $_SESSION['Email'] = $Email;
    $_SESSION['Message Preferences'] = $MessagePref;
    $_SESSION['Member Type'] = $MemberType;
    $_SESSION['Sports'] = $Sports;
    ?>
} else if (localStorage.getItem('status2') === 'user') {
    <?php
    // SQL Query To Fetch Information Of User
    $query = "SELECT Username from login where Username = '$user_check'";
    $ses_sql = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);

    $login_session = $row['Username'];


    // SQL Query To Fetch Information Of User
    $query2 = "SELECT CustCode from login where Username = '$user_check' AND Password = '$p'";
    $ses_sql2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ses_sql2);

    $cust = $row2['CustCode'];
    $_SESSION['CustCode'] = $cust;


    // SQL Query To Fetch Information Of User
    $query3 = "SELECT CustGivenName As 'Given Name', CustSurname As 'Surname' from customers where CustCode = '$cust'";
    $ses_sql3 = mysqli_query($conn, $query3);
    $row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ses_sql3);

    $name1 = $row3['Given Name'];
    $name2 = $row3['Surname'];
    $_SESSION['Given Name'] = $name1;
    $_SESSION['Surname'] = $name2;


    // SQL Query To Fetch Information Of User
    $queryAccountDeatils = "SELECT CustDob As 'Date of Birth', CustGender As 'Gender', CustAddress1 As 'Address', CustAddress2 As 'Region', CustPostCode As 'Post Code', CustPhone As 'Phone Number', CustEmail As 'Email', CustMsgPref As 'Message Preferences', CustMemberType As 'Member Type', CustSports As 'Sports' from customers where CustCode = '$cust'";
    $ses_sql4 = mysqli_query($conn, $queryAccountDeatils);
    $row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ses_sql4);

    $Dob = $row4['Date of Birth'];
    $Address = $row4['Address'];
    $Gender = $row4['Gender'];
    $Region = $row4['Region'];
    $PostCode = $row4['Post Code'];
    $PhoneNumber = $row4['Phone Number'];
    $Email = $row4['Email'];
    $MessagePref = $row4['Message Preferences'];
    $MemberType = $row4['Member Type'];
    $Sports = $row4['Sports'];
    $_SESSION['Date of Birth'] = $Dob;
    $_SESSION['Address'] = $Address;
    $_SESSION['Gender'] = $Gender;
    $_SESSION['Region'] = $Region;
    $_SESSION['Post Code'] = $PostCode;
    $_SESSION['Phone Number'] = $PhoneNumber;
    $_SESSION['Email'] = $Email;
    $_SESSION['Message Preferences'] = $MessagePref;
    $_SESSION['Member Type'] = $MemberType;
    $_SESSION['Sports'] = $Sports;
    ?>
}
</script>
```

Comment: This can never work because your PHP code is first executed, building the HTML file with the JS code in it - and it will run both branches because there is no if/else in _PHP_, imagine all the JS as mumbo-jumbo for PHP. Then, the finished HTML+JS is sent to the browser, and at that point the JS is a condition nothing in it (as the PHP code didn't output anything).

Comment: You can use PHP to conditionally generate JS but not the other way round, since first the PHP runs on your server, then the JS on your client.

Comment: Can you make an if else based on php variable?

Comment: Yes, just write a condition in PHP... without the whole `?> <script>` part and so on.

Comment: if i run, $check = "<script> sessionStorage.getItem('status2');</script>"; at the start of the file and make if part,  if ($check === 'staff'), should that fix the issue?

Comment: No, again you are trying to build a time machine. You need to have _all_ the logic in PHP that you need at that point. Because _first_ your PHP runs on your server and assembled an HTML page (which may include JS for later on - but at that point it's just text with no meaning to PHP!), and _then_ on the user's browser, the page is rendered and any JS is executed in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is executed by the server prior to sending the page content to the browser, once it has arrived in the user's browser any JS you have sent along with the HTML can be executed then.

However you will not be able to go back and run more PHP code depending on the outcome of a Javascript if statement as you are trying. You do have some options though.

**Option 1:**

Use PHP to *compose* some JS expressions or functions that will run in the client side by `echo`ing valid JS expressions into the `<scirpt>` tag. But again running your MySQL queries will have to happen first during the server-side phase.

**Option 2:**

You could also use an AJAX-style JS call to call upon a secondary PHP scripts that echo your results as JSON or some other consumable format. jQuery has AJAX functions or look into "Axios" or the browser-native "fetch()".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

**Option 3:**

Forget about Javascript if you can and write the If...Else into the PHP logic.

Comment: Can localStorage be pulled into php? If so then option 3 could work

Comment: Cookies get sent over HTTP but not session/local storage. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21481036/why-can-cookies-be-set-by-php-nut-not-local-storage

Comment: So if you want to rewrite your client side to use cookies then option 3 will work for you